# Arrange Statusbar at bottom of Window

Tags: c#, wpf

I got a little problem with my statusbar.
In my xaml

```
  <Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <Buttons etc... />

  <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemsSource="{Binding DataFields}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding FieldType}" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Unit" Binding="{Binding Unit}" />
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Values">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:DataField}">
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Values}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>

  <Grid Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  >
    <ProgressBar 
      Height="31"
               Minimum="0"
               Maximum="50"
             Value="{Binding CurrentProgress}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentProgressPercentage, StringFormat={}{0:0}%}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding ProgressVisibility}" />
  </Grid>

</Grid>
```

When my App loads, the datagrid is empty and my Grid with the statusbar is in the middle of the window. I want it to stick to the bottom border of my app. Therefore i tried to use a DockPanel instead of a Grid but this wouldnt work neither, because my grid is empty when the app is loaded. I was thinking about adding a dummy grid row but i cannot come up with a solution...

Can anyone give me a simple solution please?

Thank you!

Comment: I have tried your sample and it is working as expected: ProgressBar is docked to bottom. Is it complete example?

Comment: Problem was the xaml above is a template and im using it within another view, which was messed up... it's all fine now that I fixed the other view. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

It should help when you assign a fix height to the grid row that contains the progress bar, so change the Grid.RowDefinitions to something like:

```
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```